# PHP Regex Parse query string containing un-encoded ampersands

Tags: php, regex, parsing, query-string, ampersand

I'm receiving a query string (from a terrible payment system whose name I do not wish to sully publicly) that contains un-encoded ampersands

```
name=joe+jones&company=abercrombie&fitch&other=no
```

parse_str can't handle this, and I don't know enough of regex to come up with my own scheme (though I did try). My hang up was look-ahead regex which I did not quite understand.

What I'm looking for:

```
Array
(
    [name] => joe jones
    [company] => abercrombie&fitch
    [other] => no
)
```

I thought about traipsing through the string, ampersand by ampersand, but that just seemed silly. Help?

Comment: Are the keys (name, company, etc.) predictable / fixed?

Comment: The keys are user generated and unpredictable :(

Comment: Then there is almost no way.... unless you can say an 'empty' value (if you parsed it as a valid query string) is 100% sure not going to happen (just loop through the result of `parse_str` & add the current key to the previous value if the value of the current key is an empty string.

Comment: This is a horrible horrible bug. If you have to work with a system that does this, and the developers aren't prepared to fix it, you should be making a lot of loud noises of complaint. Developers shouldn't be allowed to get away with that kind of bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

If two ampersands occur with no `=` between them, encode the first one. Then pass the result to the normal query string parser.

That should accomplish your task. This works because the pattern for a "normal" query string should always alternate equals signs and ampersands; thus two ampersands in a row means one of them should have been encoded, and as long as keys don't have ampersands in them, the last ampersand in a row is always the "real" ampersand preceding a new key.

You should be able to use the following regex to do the encoding:

```
$better_qs = preg_replace("/&(?=[^=]*&)/", "%26", $bad_qs);
```

Comment: This looks marvelous but unfortunately will not work properly if the value has more than one ampersand in it (which is quite unlikely though).

Comment: It's close, if it could only be adapted to work with more than one ampersand.

Comment: Tatu - I adapted it to use a lookahead instead of an actual match on the second ampersand, which should allow it to work for any number of ampersands in a value.

Comment: @Amber, seems to be working now, great. Some proper RE mastery there :)

Comment: That's an impressive regex solution to a hideous problem.

Comment: This works in all cases except when the unescaped ampersand is in the last parameter of the query string. The regex needs an additional '&' appended to the end of the query string to work correctly. Is there anyway of detecting two ampersands with no = between them OR an ampersand and the end of the query string with no = in between?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the split() function to split the string by ampersands. After that, you could split again each element with the delimeter "="... something like that:

```
$myarray = split("&", $mystring);

foreach ($myarray as $element) {
  $keyvalue = split("=", $element);
  $resultarray[$keyvalue[0]] = $keyvalue[1];
}

print_r($resultarray);
```

Not tested! But you should get the idea.